# snapshot script for vmware esxi host

Tags: snapshot

I am searching for way to create scheduled snapshot creation script. With possibility to set retention days/ count.
Maybe someone can share some example or say what are using to create auto snapshots for VM

Comment: I have using veeam backup&replication free edition without using any automation.. searching way to use any atomation

Answer (score 2):

If you have enought knowledge in shell, this is the command to create snaphot:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.create $SRC/$VM/$VM.vmx
```

with :

- $SRC = datastore path
- $VM = VM folder name

As the ESXi reset some files each reboot, this is the way to add a script to crontab:

edit /etc/rc.local.d/local.sh (permanent after reboot & launched at each reboot)

```
#add to crontab a task
echo "01 00 1,15 * * root /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/script/backupVM.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
#stop crontab process
kill $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
#start crontab process
crond
```

Do not forget to set your script as executable

```
chmod +x /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/script/backupVM.sh
```

List of Esxi commands

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vcli.ref.doc_50/vcli-right.html

Here is an example of the shell scripting possibilities on ESXi:
https://github.com/Fro99666/BASH_froggESXIbackupVM/blob/master/backupVM.sh

This script create backup of VM,tar them, make a copy, and send them backup via FTP. Once finished it send a mail with the log of the process